# Formatting Web Pages for Printing

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a loop that display div tags, returning values from a database.
I'm using twitter bootstrap for the layout.
The page shows the text as expected, like a list.
But, I added a link to enable printing.
When I click the link to print the list appears like this, adding a space at it iteration of the loop:

[image]

I would like to display as a list, without the added margin on the left.

```
<div class="row">
   <ul class="unstyled">


<?php

foreach ($user_id3 as $userid) {


$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT u.*, i.item_id, i.item_name, ui.date FROM user_items ui 
INNER JOIN users u on ui.user_id = u.user_id 
INNER JOIN items i on ui.item_id = i.item_id 
WHERE u.user_id = '$userid'");

if(!$sql) {
   echo "error sql: " . mysqli_error($con);
}

$item_ids = array();
$item_names = array();
$user_companys = array();
$user_emails = array();
$user_dates = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

       $user_ids = $row['user_id'];
       $user_id4[] = $row['user_id'];
       $user_names = $row['user_name'];
       $user_companys = $row['user_company'];
       $user_emails = $row['user_email'];

       $contactable = $row['contactable'];

       $user_dates = $row['date'];

       $item_ids[] = $row['item_id'];
       $item_name = $row['item_name'];
       $item_names[] = $item_name;
}



echo "<div class='year'><div class='day'><div class='month'><div class='span12'><li><strong>Name:</strong> " . $user_names . "</li></div><br><br>";

       echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Company:</strong> ". $user_companys . "</li></div><br><br>";

       echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Email:</strong> " . $user_emails . "</li></div><br><br>";

        echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Contactable: </strong>"; 

if($contactable == 0) { 
    echo 'No'; 
} elseif ($contactable == 1) {
    echo 'Yes'; 
}


echo "</li></div><br><br>";


       $date = $user_dates;


       echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Date:</strong> ";
       echo date('j-n-Y', strtotime($date)); 
       echo "</li></div><br><br>";


echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Items requested:</strong> ";
foreach ($item_names as $item_name) {

    echo $item_name . ',';

}

echo "</li></div><br><br>";



$sql_feedback2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE user_id = '$userid'");

if(!$sql_feedback2) {
   echo "error sql_feedback2: " . mysqli_error($con);
}

$rating = array();
$recommend = array();
$comment = array();


while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_feedback2)) {

    $rating[] = $row3['rating'];
    $recommend[] = $row3['recommend'];
    $comment[] = $row3['comment'];


}

echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Rating: </strong>" . $rating[0] . "</li></div><br><br>";

echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Recommend: </strong>" . $recommend[0] . "</li></div><br><br>";

echo "<div class='span12'><li><strong>Comment: </strong>" . $comment[0] . "</li></div><br><br>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your HTML structure?

Comment: why u could not added margin left??? is there any issue with that?

Comment: I will post the code.

Comment: update your code with <ul> tag it is missing as 
echo "<div class='year'><div class='day'><div class='month'><div class='span12'><ul><li><strong>Name:</strong> " . $user_names . "</li></ul></div><br /><br />";

Comment: Thanks!!! I added <ul> tags and is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. You need to reset the `ul` with a zero `margin` and `padding`. This will remove the additional spacing.

**For Instance,**

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h7ECw/)**

**The HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="noLeftMargin">
    <li>This is a list item</li>
    <li>This is a list item</li>
    <li>This is a list item</li>
    <li>This is a list item</li>
    <li>This is a list item</li>
    <li>This is a list item</li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS Code:**

```
ul.noLeftMargin{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.noLeftMargin li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but because it is a loop, it is adding the next iteration next to the previous list, which gives the space. On the page it looks fine, but when I try to print it gives me the space.

Comment: Can you share your code for further analysis ?? - @AnaClaudia

Comment: Your HTML inside PHP is incorrect. You have not inserted UL tags as parent for LI - @AnaClaudia

Comment: I saw, but this is still incorrect : `<div class='span12'><li><strong>Company:</strong>` - @AnaClaudia

Comment: Ok, I will try to fix it.